# How to call a error message dialog function of stacked architecture in flutetr

Tags: flutter, dart, architecture, stacked

my first question here as a developer, I was building a scanner in flutter and using the stacked architecture. I want an error message to show when the code isn't scanned properly. Already worked on the UI but I'm finding it difficult on how to call the dialog function. Any help would be appreciated as I am new to this.

```
class ScanResult extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScanResult({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ScanResultState createState() => _ScanResultState();
}

class _ScanResultState extends State<ScanResult> {
  Barcode? result;
  QRViewController? controller;

  final qrkey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'QR');
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.white24,
        ),
        child: Text(
          result != null ? 'Result: ${result!.code}' : 'Scan a code!',
          maxLines: 2,
          style: const TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      
      );

}
```

Comment: means if `result!=null` show the dialog?

Comment: Why not have a condition before your Text widget that checks if there is an error or not. If there isn't one, display the text widget, if there is one, present a dialog.

Comment: @tomerpacific how do I go about writing the condition, please? Been sick, didn't even notice I have comments here. Just got back to the project again. Any sample code will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @user17550585 - you either want to return a text widget as a child of your ScanResult widget or show a dialog so instead of hardcoding the Text element, you can create a method which (depending on the result) does that.

Answer (score 0):

Create an enum that specifies the different types of dialogs.

```
/// The type of dialog to show
enum DialogType { basic, error }
```

In your UI folder or shared folder under UI, if you have one, create a new file called setup_dialog_ui.dart. Inside you will create a new function called setupDialogUi. In there you will create a Map of builders that will map to the enum values you created above. To keep code maintenance to the highest level you should make each of the widgets into its own widget and construct that instead of building the UI inline.

```
void setupDialogUi() {
final dialogService = locator<DialogService>();

final builders = {
DialogType.error: (context, sheetRequest, completer) =>
    _BasicDialog(request: sheetRequest, completer: completer),
};

 dialogService.registerCustomDialogBuilders(builders);
}
```

create a file to add your dialog

```
class _BasicDialog extends StatelessWidget {
final DialogRequest request;
final Function(DialogResponse) completer;
const _BasicDialog({Key key, this.request, this.completer}) : super(key: 
key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Dialog(
   child: /* Build your dialog UI here */
  );
 }
}
```

The DialogRequest has a few properties that can make you easily decide which widgets to place in the dialog to show. All these properties can be passed directly to the showCustomDialog function. Here are all the properties available for you to use.

```
/// The title for the dialog
final String title;

/// Text so show in the dialog body
final String description;

/// Indicates if an image should be used or not
final bool hasImage;

/// The URL / path to the image to show
final String imageUrl;

/// The text shown in the main button
final String mainButtonTitle;

/// A bool to indicate if you should show an icon in the main button
final bool showIconInMainButton;

/// The text to show on the secondary button on the dialog (cancel 
usually)
final String secondaryButtonTitle;

/// Indicates if you should show an icon in the main button
final bool showIconInSecondaryButton;

/// The text shown on the third button on the dialog
final String additionalButtonTitle;

/// Indicates if you should show an icon in the additional button
final bool showIconInAdditionalButton;

/// Indicates if the dialog takes input
final bool takesInput;

/// Intended to be used with enums. If you want to create multiple 
different

/// dialogs. Pass your enum in here and check the value in the builder
final dynamic variant;

/// Extra data to be passed to the UI
final dynamic customData;
```

After you have created your register function go to your main.dart file and after you've registered your services with the locator call setupDialogUi.

```
void main() {
 setupLocator();
 setupDialogUi();
 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Now in your ViewModels, you can make use of the dialog as follows.

```
await _dialogService.showCustomDialog(
  variant: DialogType.error, // Which builder you'd like to call that was assigned in the builders function above.
  title: 'This is a custom UI with Text as main button',
  description: 'Sheck out the builder in the dialog_ui_register.dart 
  file',
  mainButtonTitle: 'Ok',
);
```

You can use the **DialogRequest** object to access these data inside the dialog.

Do follow the instructions inside the documentation

```
https://pub.dev/packages/stacked_services
```